# Finding the longest collatz sequence for starting numbers < 100

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
def longest_collatz_sequence(n)
    longest_sequence = []
    (1..n).each do |a|
        sequence = [a]
        until sequence.last == 1
            if a % 2 == 0
                sequence.push(a/2)
            else
                sequence.push(3a + 1)
            end
        end
        if sequence.length > longest_sequence.length
            longest_sequence = sequence
        end
    end
    longest_sequence
end
```

longest_collatz_sequence(100)

When I run the algorithm, I'm told that there is an unexpected identifier within 3a + 1 and the program doesn't run. Where is my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: for this you asked a question in SO.. :) If you try in IRB, it could you help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that `3*a`, you left out the actual multiplication.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. The algorithm works for 2 but not for n > 2. Do you know why? @pjs

Comment: @user2469211 That's a different question. Please post a new question if you can't solve it yourself

Answer (score -2):

```
def seq(num)
  tryied = []
  highest_count = 0
  highest = nil 
  highest_seq = nil
  element = nil 
 arr = (1..num).to_a
 arr = arr.reverse 
 arr.each { |el| 

 if seq_count(el) > highest_count && !tryied.include?(el)
    highest_count = seq_count(el)
    highest = el 
   highest_seq = seq_arr(el)
   tryied.concat(seq_arr(el))
  end
 }
p highest
p highest_count
p highest_seq


end









def seq_count(num)
  temp = num  
  count = 1

until temp == 1 do 
  if temp.even?
     temp = temp/2 
     count += 1
  elsif temp.odd?
     temp = (3*temp) + 1 
     count += 1
  end 
end 
  count 
end 

def seq_arr(num)
    temp = num  
  arr = []
  arr << temp

until temp == 1 do 
  if temp.even?
     temp = temp/2 
     arr << temp
  elsif temp.odd?
     temp = (3*temp) + 1 
     arr << temp
  end 
end 
   arr 
end 

 seq(1000000)
```