# Finding the longest collatz sequence for any number under 100

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
def longest_collatz_sequence(n)
    longest_sequence = []
    (1..n).each do |a|
        sequence = [a]
        until sequence.last == 1
            if a % 2 == 0
                sequence.push(a/2)
            else
                sequence.push(3 * a + 1)
            end
        end
        if sequence.length > longest_sequence.length
            longest_sequence = sequence
        end
    end
    longest_sequence
end
```

longest_collatz_sequence(n) works for n = 2, but doesn't work for n > 2. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the longest collatz sequence for starting numbers < 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565924/finding-the-longest-collatz-sequence-for-starting-numbers-100)

Comment: It's not. I was asked to post the question again because the first time it was a syntax problem.

Comment: You can edit the old one

Comment: @MohanKumar No. Those are two separate questions. The answer there would not address the new problem, so it is a *very bad idea* to edit it instead of asking a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always push the same number, `a/2` or `3*a + 1` and obviously it never stops if `a/2 != 1 != 3*a + 1`. You probably want to use the last number of sequence instead of `a`:

```
if sequence.last % 2 == 0
  sequence.push(sequence.last/2)
else
  sequence.push(3 * sequence.last + 1)
end

irb> longest_collatz_sequence(3)
=> [3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

These kinds of bugs can be tracked down by using a debugger or introducing print statements at appropriate places, so that you can trace what is going on in your program. I think this might help you help yourself in the future, because not all bugs are easy to find using visual inspection alone.